# 404 Error with Spring Boot Server-Side API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I've been scratching my head on this for a while, any help is really appreciated. Below is some code I'm writing for a check in system. When I try to get to the API I just get the White Label Error page. I'm guessing that my Tomcat Apache server isn't actually starting when the app starts but I can't figure out how to change that configuration. However, when I run the server on its own I can't start the application and I get the Tomcat 404 error, not the management page.

Any help is super appreciated!

**CheckInAndStudentPortalApplication.java**

```
package com.desola.checkinandstudentportal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
public class CheckInAndStudentPortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CheckInAndStudentPortalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package com.desola.checkinandstudentportal.Controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.desola.checkinandstudentportal.DAO.StudentDAO;
import com.desola.checkinandstudentportal.Model.Student;

@RestController
public class StudentController {
    
    private StudentDAO dao;
    
    public StudentController(StudentDAO studentDao) {
        this.dao = studentDao;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/students/{studentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Student getStudent(@PathVariable Long studentId){
        return dao.getStudent(studentId);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path="/students", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Student> getAllStudents(){
        return dao.getAllStudents();
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.desola</groupId>
        <artifactId>check-in-and-student-portal</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>check-in-and-student-portal</name>
        <description>check-in-and-student-portal</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>16</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/set_tkd
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres1
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Comment: What URL did you use when you got the 404?

Comment: I see you haven't declared `package` equal to `war` inside the pom.xml. Because the maven default package is `jar`, this would explain why your app is not starting inside tomcat.

Comment: @JAsgarov I used both localhost:8080/students and localhost:8080/students/1

Comment: @dariosicily I added the packaging to my pom.xml, now when I hit the aformentioned endpoints, I just get a blank screen in a browser or an empty response in Postman, but if I hit the base URL then I get the whitepage error